# Kotlin Bytecode - How to analyze in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm-bytecode

I want to see the **compiled bytecode** so I can learn more about how it works under the cover. I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA** 15 but can't find a way to see the bytecode. What am I missing?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA comes with a bytecode viewing tool for Kotlin:

**Tools → <sup>[image: Kotlin icon]</sup> Kotlin → Show Kotlin Bytecode**

<sup>Also available through <kbd>Ctrl / ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as **Show Kotlin Bytecode** action.</sup>

It's a great tool that can jump to the corresponding bytecode when you move around in the source file. And it updates the bytecode on the fly whenever the source changes.

---

Also, I'd like to recommend [jclasslib Bytecode Viewer](https://github.com/ingokegel/jclasslib) as an external tool for low-level class files analysis (such as inspecting constant pools). Now it is also available as an [IntelliJ IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9248-jclasslib-bytecode-viewer).

Comment: @CaseyB And shortcut `ctrl+shift+a` (windows and linux) or `shift-command-a` (mac) is very usefull. Press this shortcut and then type `kotlin`!

Answer (score 5):

I use https://javap.yawk.at/ to view byte code online. Set "Kotlin" as the input language and you are good to go.

It even has an option to see the decompiled Java code via Procyon, but it might crush from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to the above answer.

**Tools → [image] Kotlin → Show Kotlin Bytecode**

Now, in the bytecode view, there is also an option to decompile the bytecode to Java. So, you can actually see both the bytecode and the equivalent java code in intellij. You even have an option to convert using JVM 8 target.