# Static data in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Please tell me, is there any difference (in terms of Java) in this examples:

1. ```
   object DefaultValues {
       val FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   class DefaultValues {
       companion object {
           val FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
       }
   }
   ```
2. Without class or object wrapper:

   ```
   const val DEFAULT_FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
   ```

   and

   ```
   val DEFAULT_FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
   ```

---

What is the true way to define?:

```
public static final int FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [Kotlin bytecode viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538049/kotlin-bytecode) to find out what these options are compiled to.

With Kotlin 1.0.2 the compiled bytecode shows that

1. `val` property in `object` or `companion object` is compiled into a `private static final` field inside the class:

   ```
    // access flags 0x1A
    private final static I FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
   ```

   and a getter, which is called when referring to the property:

   ```
    // access flags 0x1019
    public final static synthetic access$getFILES_TO_DOWNLOAD$cp()I
   ```

   From Java, the getter can be called as `DefaultValues.INSTANCE.getFILES_TO_DOWNLOAD()` or `DefaultValues.Companion.getFILES_TO_DOWNLOAD()` respectively.
2. Non-`const` top level property is compiled to the same to *(1)* with only difference that the field and getter are placed inside `FilenameKt` class now.

   But top level `const val` is compiled into a `public static final` field:

   ```
   // access flags 0x19
   public final static I DEFAULT_FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD = 100
   ```

   The same public static final field will be produced when a `const val` is declared inside an object. Also, you can achieve the same resulting bytecode if you add [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) annotation to the properties declared in *(1)*.

---

Concluding that, you can define `public static final` field using `const` or `@JvmField` either in an `object` or at top level.

Comment: how about   internal var x;? is it make var static?

Comment: @umitems, `internal` is only a visibility modifier, should not make much difference in the bytecode with a normal public `var`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see. I just tried to convert public static int x in java file to Kotlin file then I got internal var x instead.

Comment: Does it implies any difference in terms of performance and bytecode size?

Comment: @LouisCAD, `const val` and `@JvmField` are more efficient than simple `val`, but this is mostly because of the getter calls, while JVM is quite good at inlining functions and especially getters at runtime. I guess in a long run the performance difference should be negligible (for a non-critical part of the code). As to the bytecode size, the second option produces smaller bytecode as well, but your are unlikely to save much optimizing this anyway.