# What is the difference between "const" and "val"?

Tags: constants, kotlin

I have recently read about the `const` keyword, and I'm so confused! I can't find any difference between `const` and the `val` keyword, I mean we can use both of them to make an immutable variable, is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants

Comment: You can read this article https://www.android4dev.com/difference-between-var-val-and-const-in-kotlin/
 or Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQLrEGqSSI8&t=6s

Answer (score 628, accepted):

`const`s are compile time constants. Meaning that their value has to be assigned during compile time, unlike `val`s, where it can be done at runtime.

This means that only a String or primitive can be assigned to a `const`, not the result of a function or class constructor invocation.

For example:

```
const val foo = complexFunctionCall()   //Not okay
val fooVal = complexFunctionCall()      //Okay

const val bar = "Hello world"           //Also okay
```

Comment: What about something like this: `const val foo = "Hello world"` and `val bar = "Hello world"`? Are they the same?

Comment: @MathewHany, at least not in terms of bytecode, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482378/static-data-in-kotlin/37485356#37485356

Comment: I think `const` values will just be completely inlined during compilation.

Comment: This begs another question: Why does Kotlin require `const val` instead of just `const`? It seems to me the `val` keyword is totally superfluous in this context, since `const var` would be absurd on its face.

Comment: Then why the differentiation? Why can't the compiler determine if a value is a const and compute its value at compile time if it is?

Comment: `const val` is underlined with red with a message: `Modifier 'const' is not applicable to 'local variable'` inside a function.

Comment: @EricLloyd With `const val`, `const` is a modifier on `val` rather than a keyword. Modifiers > keywords. More examples of this same design are, `annotation/enum/data class`, `private val`, `inline fun`, etc.

Comment: since consts are assigned at compile time, when the object is destroyed by GC will the constants be free or do they reside forever ?

Comment: @Aro So in other words, a constant modifying a constant. Yeah makes sense (rolls eyes).

Comment: @EricLloyd A `const` is inlined by the compiler which you don't always want because it requires recompilation in order the change the value

Comment: @FlorianWalther Yeah, that's kinda the idea -- I typically use `const`s for truly immutable values -- HTTP verbs, the value of Pi, etc. If it's a mutable or even configurable value, a `const` isn't the answer.

Comment: seeing how Kotlin is superior because it reduces nosiness of unnecessary tings, "val" in "const val" is totally useless, unless of course you can write "const var" which is nonsense.

Comment: @EricLloyd totally agree with you. However, comparing with all the superises brough by `const` and `constexpr` from c++11 to c++20, I would say, this is reality, nothing is perfect.

Comment: @Dainius, I'm guessing it's done out of necessity because `const` is a soft keyword. You can use it as a variable or function name. If you could write `const` without `val`, it would have to be a hard keyword.

Answer (score 58):

Just to add to Luka's answer:

> **Compile-Time Constants**
>
> Properties the value of which is known at compile time can be marked as compile time constants using the const modifier. Such properties need to fulfill the following requirements:
>
> - Top-level or member of an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) or a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).
> - Initialized with a value of type String or a primitive type
> - No custom getter
>
> Such properties can be used in annotations.

Source: [Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants)

Answer (score 40):

You can transform the Kotlin to Java.
Then you can see **const** has one more **static** modifier than **val**.
The simple code like this.

Kotlin:

```
const val str = "hello"
class SimplePerson(val name: String, var age: Int)
```

To Java(Portion):

```
@NotNull
public static final String str = "hello";

public final class SimplePerson {
   @NotNull
   private final String name;
   private int age;

   @NotNull
   public final String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public final int getAge() {
      return this.age;
   }

   public final void setAge(int var1) {
      this.age = var1;
   }

   public SimplePerson(@NotNull String name, int age) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(name, "name");
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could someone state in a comment why this answer was downvoted to oblivion?

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor I upvoted. But I assume it's because some people didn't read it carefully, and at a quick glance this answer seems to be talking about how to convert from java to kotlin, which would be off-topic.

Comment: What if `const` is removed, will it yield a different Java file?

Comment: @DYS: I think it will remove the "static" and it will be just public final String str = "hello";

Comment: @DYS compare it to `SimplePerson`'s `private final String name;` which doesn't have the const and then is private as well, but that's because it's a member val instead of a top-level/package val and not because of the `const`.

Answer (score 31):

**const kotlin to Java**

```
const val Car_1 = "BUGATTI" // final static String Car_1 = "BUGATTI";
```

**val kotlin to Java**

```
val Car_1 = "BUGATTI"   // final String Car_1 = "BUGATTI";
```

**In simple Language**

1. The value of the const variable is known at compile time.
2. The value of val is used to define constants at run time.

**Example 1-**

```
const val Car_1 = "BUGATTI" ✔  
val Car_2 = getCar() ✔    
const val Car_3 = getCar() ❌ 

//Because the function will not get executed at the compile time so it will through error

fun getCar(): String {
    return "BUGATTI"
}
```

This is because getCar() is evaluated at run time and assigns the value to Car.

**Additionally -**

1. **val** is read-only means immutable that is known at run-time
2. **var** is mutable that is known at run-time
3. **const** are immutable and variables that are known at compile-time

Answer (score 24):

Both `val` and `const` are immutable.

`const` is used to declare compile-time constants, whereas `val` for run-time constants.

```
const val VENDOR_NAME = "Kifayat Pashteen"  // Assignment done at compile-time

val PICon = getIP()  // Assignment done at run-time
```

Comment: Compile-time happens before run-time, right?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat yes. The code is compiled before being sent for execution. The point of time when the code executes is what is essentially known as run-time execution.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Yes compile-time happen before runtime.

Comment: `val` is not necessarily immutable.

Answer (score 12):

Because I read a lot, that "val" means immutable: This is definitely not the case, just see this example:

```
class Test {
    var x: Int = 2
    val y
        get() = x
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test = Test()
    println("test.y = ${test.y}") // prints 2
    test.x = 4
    println("test.y = ${test.y}") // prints 4
}
```

Sadly, true immutability you can currently only expect with const - but this only at compile time. At runtime you can't create true immutability.

val just means "readonly", you can't change this variable directly, only indirect like I have shown in the example above.

Comment: wow, remarkable!

Comment: it *is* immutable even in your example. you defined y as a *function* which returns whatever is in x. this function cannot be re-assinged to another function

Comment: You are just returning a value of another variable through overriden getter method! You are NOT MUTATING Y i.e not reassigning it!

Answer (score 8):

Let's learn this by an example.

```
object Constants {

    val NAME = "Amit"

}
```

Note: We are not using `const`.

And, we are accessing this `NAME` as below:

```
fun testValWithoutConst() {
    val name = Constants.NAME
}
```

Now, we need to decompile this code. For that, we will have to convert this Kotlin source file to a Java source file.

We will get the following output:

```
public final void testValWithoutConst() {
  String name = Constants.INSTANCE.getNAME();
}
```

The output is as expected.

The above example was without the `const` keyword. Now, let's use the `const` keyword.

For that, we will modify our object class `Constants` in Kotlin as below:

```
object Constants {

    const val NAME = "Amit"

}
```

Note: We are using `const`.

And, we are accessing this `NAME` as below:

```
fun testValWithConst() {
    val name = Constants.NAME
}
```

Now, when we decompile this code, we will get the following output:

```
public final void testValWithConst() {
  String name = "Amit";
}
```

Here, we can see that the variable `NAME` has been replaced by its value which is `Amit`.

As the value has been inlined, there will be **no overhead to access that variable at runtime**. And hence, it will lead to a better performance of the application.

This is the advantage of using `const` in Kotlin.

Reference from my blog: [Advantage of using const in Kotlin](https://amitshekhar.me/blog/const-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 7):

## val

Kotlin `val` keyword is for **read-only** properties in comparison with Kotlin `var` keyword. The other name for `read-only` property is `immutable`.

Kotlin code:

```
val variation: Long = 100L
```

Java equivalent looks like this:

```
final Long variation = 100L;
```

## const val

We use `const` keyword for immutable properties too. `const` is used for properties that are known at compile-time. That's the difference. Take into consideration that `const` property must be declared **`globally`**.

Kotlin code (in playground):

```
const val WEBSITE_NAME: String = "Google"

fun main() {    
    println(WEBSITE_NAME)
}
```

Java code (in playground):

```
class Playground {

    final static String WEBSITE_NAME = "Google";

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        System.out.println(WEBSITE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read-only is not the same thing as immutable so the second sentence of this answer is false. You can have a read-only `val` that produces different results on multiple calls through a custom getter or because it’s a delegated property, or because it’s open and has a setter in a subclass

Comment: "Kotlin val keyword is for read-only properties" if so then why do you write to it in your example?

Comment: @Tenfour04 read-only === immutable, see my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595936/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-val#comment132669180_70486344

Comment: @MarkoBjelec Counterexamples to what you're saying: https://pl.kotl.in/DZ-c6drq0

Answer (score 7):

For those who are looking which is more appropriate or efficient between `val` and `const`:

For the String or any primitive data type `const val` is recommended to use instead of `val`. Because `val` will be known at runtime, so when your app is running then it will process all the values. On other hand `const val` will do this earlier at compile time. So performance wise `const val` will give better result.