# Kotlin - what's the reasoning behind "const"

Tags: kotlin, constants

It has been already clarified what's the difference between `val` and `const val` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595936/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-val).

But my question is, why we should use `const` keyword? There is no difference from the generated Java code perspective.

This Kotlin code:

```
class Application

private val testVal = "example"

private const val testConst = "another example"
```

Generates:

```
public final class ApplicationKt
{
    private static final String testVal = "example";
    private static final String testConst = "another example";
}
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: If you try assigning a value to a const after the initialisation, the compiler can pick this up as a possible bug. By defining a constant, you are telling the compiler (and developers, including yourself) that this value is not intended to change.

Comment: @JamesB What do you think happens if you try assigning a value to a non-`const` `val`?

Comment: I'm surprised no-one mentioned this. The other BIG difference is the compiler will inline a const. Try reference testVal and testConst in Kotlin code to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

It's not always the same generated code.

If `testVal` and `testConst` were `public`, the generated code wouldn't be the same. `testVal` would be `private` with a `public` `get`, whereas `testConst` would be `public`, without any getter. So `const` avoids generating a getter.

Comment: That's true - for public fields we will have getter. But that would mean that for `private const val` we should be notified that `const` is a redundant modifier.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the main difference is that `val` means that no setter will be generated for the property (but a getter will be generated) and not that the value is constant, while a `const val` is a constant (like a Java's `private/public static final xxx`).

Example:

```
class Foo {
    private val testVal: String
        get() = Random().nextInt().toString()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As directly mentioned in the documentation, `testConst` can be used in annotation parameters, but `testVal` can't.

More generally speaking, `const` *guarantees* that you have a constant variable in the Java sense, and

> [Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1), reachability (§14.21), and definite assignment (§16.1.1).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the difference between generated code because your variables are `private`. Otherwise the result would have the `getter` for `testVal`:

```
  public final class ApplicationKt {
       @NotNull
       private static final String testVal = "example";
       @NotNull
       public static final String testConst = "another example";

       @NotNull
       public static final String getTestVal() {
          return testVal;
       }
    }
```

So in your particular case it is the same, except you can use `const` properties in `annotations`:

```
const val testVal: String = "This subsystem is deprecated"
@Deprecated(testVal) fun foo() { ... }
```

Comment: That's true - for private fields there is no difference. But that would mean that for private const val we should be notified that const is a redundant modifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are also differences in using them.

Example of constants(Kotlin):

```
class Constants {
    companion object {
        val EXAMPLE1 = "example1" // need companion and a getter
        const val EXAMPLE2 = "example2" // no getter, but companion is generated and useless
        @JvmField val EXAMPLE3 = "example3"; // public static final with no getters and companion
    }
}
```

How to use(Java):

```
public class UseConstants {
    public void method(){
        String ex1 = Constants.Companion.getEXAMPLE1();
        String ex2 = Constants.EXAMPLE2;
        String ex3 = Constants.EXAMPLE3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Consts" are compile time Constants whereas "val" is used to define constants at run time.
This means, that "consts" can never be assigned to a function or any class constructor, but only to a String or primitive.

Example:

```
const val NAME = "M Sakamoto"
val PICon = getPI()

fun getPI(): Double {
 return 3.14
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println("Name : $NAME")
  println("Value of PI : $PICon")
 }
```

Output:

```
Name : M Sakamoto
Value of PI : 3.14
```