# Accessing abstract inner class variables from another abstract inner class (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to access `TABLE_NAME` from `ProductTable` in `ProductImageTable` to put it in the query. I've searched everywhere on how to access it and so far I've found nothing. I would appreciate some help, please :)

Here's a snippet of the code :

```java
abstract inner class ProductTable : Table() {
    val TABLE_NAME: String = "product"
}

abstract inner class ProductImageTable : Table() {
    val SQL_CREATE_TABLE : String = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME" +
            " ($_ID$ID_TYPE_AUTO_INC$COMMA_SEP" +
            "$COLUMN_PRODUCT_UUID$TEXT_TYPE_NOT_NULL$COMMA_SEP" +
            "$COLMUN_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE$TEXT_TYPE_NOT_NULL_EMPTY$COMMA_SEP" +
            "$COLUMN_SERVER_IMAGE_URL$TEXT_TYPE_NOT_NULL_EMPTY$COMMA_SEP" +
            "FOREIGN KEY($COLUMN_PRODUCT_UUID) REFERENCES ${ProductTable.TABLE_NAME}(${ProductTable.COLUMN_PRODUCT_UUID}) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
abstract inner class ProductImageTable : ProductTable() {
```

if you inherit from that class where that field is then you should be able to access it.

Also you could make your TABLE_NAME val a `const` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37596023/2399024 for mor infos about const):

```
const val TABLE_NAME: String = "product"
```

BTW: Maybe you might want to use https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room instead of manually doing sql query stuff

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)  I put everything in an companion object, so I can now access the variables.