# How const val and val inside a companion object are different?

Tags: kotlin

I am wondering what is the difference between

```
companion object {
 const val a = "hi"
}
```

And

```
companion object {
 val a = "hi"
}
```

in terms of its internal implementation or the way its converted to bytecode. Apart from the fact the a const value is known at compile time what difference it makes? I saw some related questions but did not get enough details from it.

Comment: Surely you have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37595936/5133585)? What are you looking for that is not already in those 12 answers?

Comment: What I could understand from that post is about value being known at compile/run time and while converting to bytecode it could be different but did not really get how exactly it is different or why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "const" and "val"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595936/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-val)

Comment: The key difference and reason for using `const` is in the Kotlin documentation: “The compiler will inline usages of the constant, replacing the reference to the constant with its actual value.” This has a potential performance benefit.