# Java/Kotlin interesting local variable behavior

Tags: java, kotlin

I've noticed some unexpected behavior with a local variable in a function for Kotlin/Java. The following function was called concurrently several times, and sometimes the value of the variable `temp` is false instead of true.

What's more peculiar is that, I've verified that `temp` is set to `true` in every function invocation, but for some, it turns back to false in `onTerminate`.

My expectation was that for each function invocation, a new memory address will be used for the `temp` variable as long as the `temp` variable is not garbage collected. Since the variable is included in the callback/listener Completable, shouldn't it stay in memory, and so `temp` should always be true in the `onTerminate` section?
What is going on here?

```
fun getCompletable() {
    var temp = false
    return Completable.create {
        acquireLock()
        temp = true
        ...
    }.onTerminate {
        println(temp) // temp is sometimes true and sometimes false
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a race condition; this isn't going to be a memory sharing issue.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your reply. The above code is pretty much the entirety of the code. Given the above code, isn't a race condition with `temp` impossible since `temp` is not modified otherwise anywhere?

Comment: `temp` is only set to `true` when the `onSubscribe` callback you pass to `create` is invoked - if you never subscribe to the `Completable`, it will never run, so `temp` will still be `false` when the `Completable` is terminated.

Comment: @superhawk610 That is what I initially thought. However, I've verified that temp is set to true in every function invocation, but for some of the invocations, it turns back to false in onTerminate. Which is why I suspected something with memory address being reused, which seems unlikely but I don't know why else it would happen.

Comment: Can you update your code sample to include how `getCompletable` is being called?

Comment: I'm not sure the java tag is relevant; java does not allow you to mutate any local that is used inside a closure. I don't know how kotlin implement this, but if it just hoists into heap, then you're seeing what always happens when you write/read to the same field from 2 different threads: Coin flips as to whether you can observe the change, or not. That's _WHY_ java doesn't allow you to do it, I assume Kotlin decided that was annoying and made an error in that determination that shows up here.

Comment: The problem is that the captured `temp` is not volatile. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479009/kotlin-local-variable-thread-safety

Comment: @broot Thanks for the answer, this is the correct explanation I believe. I had checked the decompiled java code while debugging, and indeed they were ObjectRefs.