# Are Kotlin data types built off primitive or non-primitive Java data types?

Tags: java, int, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and was playing around with the data types. I took an `Int` type and then tried to cast it as a `Double` by saying `num as Double`, a call that is valid in java (non syntactically but you get the point). However, this failed, saying that Int cannot be cast to Double. I am assuming this is because it is built off the Integer class rather than the raw int data type. Am I correct, and what is the most efficient way to cast values? There is a `.toDouble()` function, but this seems inefficient and unwieldy.

Comment: The big takeaway from the answers below is that numbers are treated like objects in koltin (and must be explicitly converted), but the compiler uses primitives where possible to maximize performance and efficiency, so don't worry about that.

Comment: This is 2017 - in 99.9% of cases, numerical manipulation being efficient doesn't matter. I have worked on cases where it did, thermal modelling and such, but rare is the case where such a worry is not a micro-optimization and a waste of time.

Comment: @corsiKa A lot of us needs to know this information, it's still as important as it was 10 years ago. Why do you think they are improving SIMD support in the processors? Also any kind of image or audio manipulation would be terribly inefficient if you would not think of this

Comment: @jontro You seem to have not read my comment. I have worked on case swhere it did matter - billion+ polygon thermal modelling scenarios on Beowulf clusters. Definitely, it can matter. However, the vast, overwheming, monstrously huge majority, literally at least 99% (not exaggerating) will not care. For every engineer doing audio manipulation there are 100 pumping out another internal webapp for Big Company Inc to replace a spreadsheet that keeps getting deleted off a corporate shared drive.

Comment: @corsiKa I read your commend fully, but still this is a valid and good question, a lot of subjects here on SO are on specialized knowledge

Comment: Hey I didn't cast a close vote (and as a Java Gold Badge holder I can actually insta-close...), or even downvote. It's a good question in its own right, there's no doubt about that. But sometimes people think they have problems they really don't have. It's important to keep perspective on what the real problems are.

Comment: No disagreement here, nothing good comes out of premature optimizations

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I took an `Int` type and then tried to cast it as a `Double` by saying `num as Double` <...> However, this failed, saying that Int cannot be cast to `Double`. I am assuming this is because it is built off the `Integer` class rather than the raw `int` data type.

No, and there are two important points to note:

- Kotlin positions its numeric types (`Int`, `Long`, `Double` etc.) as not being nested into each other, there is **no** subtyping relationship between these types. That's why the cast `intNum as Double` does not succeed in Kotlin. That's also why there's no implicit conversions between these types. Instead, [the numeric conversion is done with the corresponding functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions) (e.g. `.toDouble()`)
- The numeric type usages in Kotlin are compiled into JVM primitives where possible. Some usages require boxed types (e.g. a nullable `Int?` requires boxing, and so does a generic type implementation with an `Int` as a type argument), but the compiler decides whether they are necessary for each case.

> <...> What is the most efficient way to cast values? There is a `.toDouble()` function, but this seems inefficient and unwieldy.

The most efficient way is to use the numeric conversion functions like `.toDouble()`. In fact, these functions are *intrinsified*, and there is no function call overhead when you use them. They are compiled closely to what javac would produce for a Java numeric cast or an implicit conversion. You can [inspect the bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538049/kotlin-bytecode) that the Kotlin compiler produces to find out what it's under the hood and whether a specific conversion introduces any overhead.

See also: an answer to a similar question, [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080746/2196460)

Answer (score 13):

This is because Kotlin does not work like Java in widening numbers.

There are no implicit widening conversions for [numbers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#numbers) in Kotlin. for example, you can write something in Java as below:

```
int a = 1;
double b = a;
```

However, you can't write something in Kotlin. for example:

```
val a:Int = 1  
//             v--- can't be widening
val b:Double = a
```

This is because everything in Kotlin is object, there is no primitive types, so you should convert an `Int` to a `Double` explicitly, for example:

```
val a:Int = 1  
//               v--- convert it explicitly by `toDouble()` method
val b:Double = a.toDouble()
```

Comment: @BasilBourque hi, I'm sorry I'm not good at english. How about it now?

Comment: I understand the technical issue, but the English was not clear. I edited the text in the Answer to clarify. And your English is not bad, quite good and clear actually, just this one glitch.