# How do I compare a Short with an Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `Short` variable that I need to check the value of. But the compiler complains that `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Short' and 'Int'` when I do a simple equals check:

```
val myShort: Short = 4
if (myShort == 4) // <-- ERROR
    println("all is well")
```

So what's the simplest, "cleanest" way to do this equals check?

Here are some things I tried.

The first one casts the 4 integer to a short (looks weird, invoking a function on a primitive number)

```
val myShort: Short = 4
if (myShort == 4.toShort())
    println("all is well")
```

The next one casts the short to an int (shouldn't be necessary, now I have two ints when I shouldn't really need any)

```
val myShort: Short = 4
if (myShort.toInt() == 4)
    println("all is well")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, the 'cleanest' way to compare it with a small constant is `myShort == 4.toShort()`.

But if you want to compare a `Short` with a wider-type variable, convert `myShort` instead to avoid the overflow: `myShort.toInt() == someInt`.

> looks weird, invoking a function on a primitive number

But it does not actually call the functions, they are intrinsified and compiled to bytecode that operates the numbers in a way that is natural for JVM, for example, the bytecode for `myShort == 4.toShort()` is:

```
ILOAD 2      // loads myShort
ICONST_4     // pushes int constant 4
I2S          // converts the int to short 4
IF_ICMPNE L3 // compares the two shorts
```

See also: [another Q&A concerning numeric conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420806/are-kotlin-data-types-built-off-primitive-or-non-primitive-java-data-types).

Comment: `It does not actually call the .toShort() function` Be that as it may, seeing `4.toShort()` will get some time to get used to...

Comment: @gromit190, `4 as Short` will not work, see the Q&A I referenced for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420806/are-kotlin-data-types-built-off-primitive-or-non-primitive-java-data-types

Comment: (Removed my previous comment) yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an *infix* function instead of `==`. I called it `eq`

```
infix fun Short.eq(i: Int): Boolean = this == i.toShort()
```

And you can use it like this

```
val myShort: Short = 4
if (myShort eq 4)
    println("all is well")
```