# Kotlin value vs. reference in assignment

Tags: class, oop, object, reference, kotlin

I would need to have one class reference another. Not create a copy of it but have an actual reference to an already existing instance.

I might be able to explain it better with an example. Were we have a class `Image`:

```
class Image(imgPath: String) {
    val height   : Int
    val width    : Int
    val rgbMatrix: MutableList< MutableList< Triple<Int, Int, Int> > >

    /* ... etc. ... */
}
```

Now say I want a class `ImageManager` that only has a reference to an already existing `Image`:

```
class ImageManager(val img: Image) {
   /* ... */
}
```

So I can have this behaviour:

```
val image = Image("/res/images/image.png")

val imageManager = ImageManager(image)

// Setting the pixel at (125, 25) to black
imageManager.img.rgbMatrix[125, 25] = Triple(0, 0, 0)

// Should print the update value(0, 0, 0)
print( image.rgbMatrix[125, 25] )
```

My questions are:

1. In Kotlin when does in assignment assign a reference and when does it assign a copy?
2. How can I determine what kind of assignment happens when?
3. Is there a part in the official docs where this is detailed? If there is I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I did not because my question is not about this particular case. It would of course be trivial to try *this* example, but in the larger project that I am working on getting to the state and conditions where I need this behaviour and testing it sufficiently would be extremely hard, so I am looking for a general answer :)

Answer (score 10):

[Similar to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), Kotlin never implicitly copies objects on assignment. Variables always hold references to objects, and assigning an expression to a variable only copies a reference to the object, not the object itself.

Under the hood, each value is either a primitive (`Int`, `Boolean`, `Char` etc.) or a reference. When a value is assigned, the result is either a copy of the primitive, or a copy of the reference to the same object, which never leads to the referenced object being copied.

As far as I can tell, this behavior is not explicitly documented; instead, it is assumed to be the same to that in Java.

See also: [Is Kotlin “pass-by-value” or “pass-by-reference”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515031/is-kotlin-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Thank you! Now, is there a list of which types are primitive and which are not? I mean in java it is obvious, primitive types are not object, you just instantiate them like in C, but here, where there are no explicit primitive types...

Comment: Actually, from the perspective of the type system and language, Kotlin does not have primitive types at all, they are mostly an implementation detail (see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420806/are-kotlin-data-types-built-off-primitive-or-non-primitive-java-data-types)). You can check the list of the JVM primitive types to find out which types *can be optimized to primitives* on JVM (these are [numeric types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#numbers), plus `Char` and `Boolean`).