# kotlin coroutines. Difference between launch{ fun} and launch {suspend fun}

Tags: kotlin, suspend, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there any difference in execution between?

```
launch {
    function1()
}
fun function1(){
    DoSomething...
}
```

And

```
launch {
   function2()
}
suspend fun function2(){
   DoSomething...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Semantically, a call to a suspending function may suspend the execution, which may be resumed at some point later (or never), possibly in a different context (e.g. another thread).

To ensure this, the compiler handles calls to a suspending function in a special way: it produces the code that saves the current local variables into a `Continuation` instance and passes it to the suspending function, and there's also a resumption point in the bytecode after the call, to which the execution will jump, load the local variables and run on (with a corner case of tail calls).

A call to a non-suspending function is compiled to much simpler bytecode, the same to normally calling a function outside a suspending function body.

You can find details about Kotlin coroutines design and implementation here: [Coroutines for Kotlin](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#implementation-details)

You can also inspect the resulting compiled bytecode to see the difference: [Kotlin Bytecode - How to analyze in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538049/kotlin-bytecode-how-to-analyze-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Let me add in a few cents

You are basically asking for the difference between a function and a suspended function.

A coroutine is like a thread only that it doesn't take so much of computer memory. You can start 100,000 coroutines with ease.
A suspend function is basically just a function but with a special call scope. It can only be called from coroutines and other suspended functions.
From the official Kotlin documentation, it says

> Suspend functions are only allowed to be called from a coroutine or
>   another suspend function. Let's dig a little into what it means. The biggest merit of coroutines is that they can suspend without blocking a thread. The compiler has to emit some special code to make this possible, so we have to mark functions that may suspend explicitly in the code.